# Why route Restful requests through a .htaccess file vs a router (front controller)?

Tags: php, rest, restful-url

Backstory:
I am attempting build an API with REST architecture where performance is numero uno.

Team has experience with a solution (from a previous project) that routes all calls through an .htaccess file that then forwards to correct controller (.htaccess->controller(resource)->response).  This is pretty fast, but the code isn't very flexible nor does it adhere to SOLID principles (overall I find it difficult to work with, plain and simple).

The current model is based off of [http://coreymaynard.com/](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/)
Example:

```
.htaccess file:
RewriteRule api/logins/(.*)$ api/controllers/Logins.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
Controller:
logins->get_login; logins->post_login; etc etc.  Extends a base class that reads the request and builds what method to execute.
```

I have been doing some serious research into API solutions and frameworks; Slim, Phalcon, Laravel, etc etc, with some basic (and mostly biased) performance testing for comparison with the adhoc system. The adhoc outperformed Slim and was neck to neck with Phalcon - we are not going with phalcon because it's not that well trusted within the team.  So our solution is to write a minimal php application.  I do not want to use the existing API system, and do something akin to a front controller.

I really like how Slim constructs resource routes, like so:

```
$app = new Slim/Slim();
//Add Get Route
$app->get('/my/route', Function/Map to Object/Do something else);
```

To me, this is readable, easy to maintain, and even easier to scale.  Then I discovered this little gem on the web:
[Small and Fast Controller with PHP](http://we-love-php.blogspot.de/2012/07/how-to-write-really-small-and-fast.html)

Based on these examples, I prototyped out a route controller and shared it with my team.

Questions:

1) What kind of performance hit am I going to see as I add additional routes? I haven't been satisfied with the information out there with executing routes this way (very procedural, stops handled by exceptions), nor do I have the experience to make assumptions.

2a) Am I being too cynical of the .htaccess method of routing?  Is the server overhead generated for parsing an .htaccess file any real concern?

2b) Has anyone had experience building php applications or REST applications this way?

And as always, thank you for taking the time to read and respond.

UPDATE:  We are moving to an Nginx server, meaning limited access to defining routes through Nginx's config and decided on a front controller to define our routes.

Answer (score 0):

"UPDATE: We are moving to an Nginx server, meaning limited access to defining routes through Nginx's config and decided on a front controller to define our routes."

This screams to me that defining routes through .htaccess is ill advised. Your front controller should theoretically work on nginx or apache without modification, and your application would continue to operate as expected. I believe you've made the right decision.